# How do I stop a MySQL decimal field from being rounded?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL with a field that is decimal, length 9, unsigned. I'm using it for prices.

After I insert the data, and query for it, it has all been rounded and the decimal has been removed.

I'm confused as to why.

Troubleshooting tips?

---

**Host**: web.com

**phpMyAdmin version**: 2.11.10.1

**MySQL client version**: 5.0.95

Comment: which data type did you give for it in the db?

Comment: What exactly is the declaration of your decimal field? What maximum number of digits and scale are declared?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Decimal type in MySQL has two tuning knobs: precision and scale. You omitted the scale, so it defaults to 0.

### Documentation ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html))

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

### Example

```
mysql> create table test01 (field01 decimal(9));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into test01 (field01) values (123.456);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test01;
+---------+
| field01 |
+---------+
|     123 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table test02 (field01 decimal(9, 4));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test02 (field01) values (123.456);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from test02;
+----------+
| field01  |
+----------+
| 123.4560 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Aha. When the field on the table creation page in phpmyadmin said Length/Values I thought it was a one or the other situation. I'm completely new to SQL so I had no idea. Thanks. Now I just have to re-enter all my data -.-

Comment: @Zuko: Glad to help. By the way, you should accept helpful answers. This will help future readers/visitors and reward the answerers :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Turns out PHPMyAdmin ignores the decimal place if you enter and assumes it to be 0. 
Use alter table query to change it. 
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `rate` `rate` DECIMAL(30,3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

Answer (score 0):

THe rounding is done because may be you have set its datatype as `int`.

Change its datatype to `double` OR `Float`.

This will help you out.

**EDIT**

If you are having datatype `decimal` give its size like this edit.

```
create table numbers (a decimal(10,2));
```

Comment: The datatype for the field is Decimal. I guess I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

The rounding is happening because you need to declare the precision in the type declaration

```
create table test01 (field01 decimal(9,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP/MySQLAdmin go to the Structure of the table, hit change and then set the length (which defaults to 10,0) to 10,2 for financial data (dollars).