# MySQL SELECT query rounding double to 12 places after decimal

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following MySQL query in PHP:

```
function queryTagsTable($tag) {
    global $pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT id, latitude, longitude FROM tbl WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM `tbl_tags` WHERE tag = :tag)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare ( $sql );
    $stmt->bindValue(':tag', $tag);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo $row['id'].', '.$row['latitude'].', '.$row['longitude'].' ';
        }
    }
}
```

In my db, I have the following result for the equivalent raw sql query:

```
276     32.082504109184285  34.89628862589598
```

Yet, the echo from my PHP code seems to always round the latitude and longitude results to 12 places after the decimal, yielding:

```
276, 32.082504109184, 34.896288625896
```

In my DB, id is an INTEGER, while latitude and longitude are DOUBLEs. I'd like for the PHP query to return the full values for latitude and longitude in order to produce maximum precision. What can I do to receive the full value of these results from my PHP function?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594456/how-do-i-stop-a-mysql-decimal-field-from-being-rounded

Comment: @Rajarshi Goswami that link doesn't apply since are different data types and that answer applies only to `DECIMAL` type

Comment: @RajarshiGoswami so you're suggesting that I just change my data types in latitude and longitude to DECIMAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that doubles have different precision in MySQL and PHP. Try casting the doubles to strings so that PHP doesn't automatically convert them:

```
SELECT id, CAST(latitude AS CHAR(32)) AS latitude, CAST(longitude AS CHAR(32)) AS longitude FROM tbl WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM `tbl_tags` WHERE tag = :tag)
```

Comment: this did not work for me.  the latitude and longitude returned empty

Comment: Yes, you're right. Though apparently when i run your example the floats load fine.

Comment: Are you running through the raw sql or php? When you run the php code it returns the full values from my table and not those rounded only to 12 places?

Comment: I tried both through PHP, phpMyAdmin and mysql client and it's fine. I'm using PHP 5.5.1

Comment: I have updated my answer, please use the new version.

Comment: thanks for updating the answer, but that solution is still not returning any values for me for latitude and longitude. i'm using php 5.4.24 and mysql 5.6.19 if that makes any difference

Comment: I have mysql 5.6.11 . Have you seen the changes to the `CHAR` part? I have tested and works.

Comment: Indeed that query works perfectly in phpMyAdmin, but the copy/pasted query in php fails to return latitude and longitude in my implementation. Not sure what the problem is.  I think I'm just going to switch to DECIMAL and call it a day. Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: It's fixed now. Column aliases were needed in order to get them by name in PHP

Comment: And it works! Thanks for the persistence. I'll accept the answer, though I'll probably use DECIMAL anyways, because it seems to be cleaner and more appropriate after having done some research on the subject