# MySQL rounding weirdness

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an invoice module and ran into some rounding weirdness when I was calculating round off amounts that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.

When executing this query in a mysql shell I get different results:

```
SELECT @amount := 1.005 AS decimalAmount, @rounded := ROUND(@amount) AS rounded, @diff := ROUND(@rounded - @amount, 2) AS roundOff, ROUND(@diff * 1e2) centsRounded;
```

The third time I run the query it shows the results I'm looking for but the first and second time is does not for some reason.

```
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------+
| decimalAmount | rounded | roundOff | centsRounded |
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|         1.005 |       1 |    -0.00 |           -0 |
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

+---------------+---------+----------+--------------+
| decimalAmount | rounded | roundOff | centsRounded |
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|         1.005 |       1 |    -0.00 |           -0 |
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

+---------------+---------+----------+--------------+
| decimalAmount | rounded | roundOff | centsRounded |
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|         1.005 |       1 |    -0.01 |           -1 |
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: [**See here for reference links to the documentation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594456/how-do-i-stop-a-mysql-decimal-field-from-being-rounded)

Comment: While I am not sure that this is it: MySQL is not required to set variables/evaluate your expressions from left to right (so they can contain old values). Have you tried running those as separate queries? (first: `select @amount = ...`, then `select @rounded = ....` and so on), or by replacing the variables by the actual expressions/values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain why this is happening?

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) explains

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is
>   undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1
>   evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.

Pretty sure the evaluation is wrong in your query.

MySQL User variables are tricky avoid them if you don't really need them.

I am more tempted to rewrite this query.

```
SELECT
    @amount := 1.005 AS decimalAmount
  , @rounded := ROUND(@amount) AS rounded
  , @diff := ROUND(@rounded - @amount, 2) AS roundOff
  , ROUND(@diff * 1e2) centsRounded;
```

More or less like (there are more rewrite options) to avoid using MySQL's user variables.

```
SELECT 
   record.amount
 , ROUND(record.amount) AS rounded
 , ROUND(ROUND(record.amount) - record.amount, 2) AS roundOff
 , ROUND(ROUND(record.amount) - record.amount, 2) * 1e2  AS centsRounded
FROM (
  SELECT 
   1.005 AS amount
) AS record
```

**Result**

```
| amount | rounded | roundOff | centsRounded |
| ------ | ------- | -------- | ------------ |
| 1.005  | 1       | -0.01    | -1           |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sXVnvQqwdAZPgVJG7FqHkC/0)

Comment: Seen warnings before about not using user variables but have never bothered on reading up on why not to... now I know. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: It was not meant to sound ignorant but I see now that it does, sorry about that. I've managed to missed all the parts on order of evaluation which is very important obviously. Thanks!