# Eloquent can't store decimal values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've been trying to save the product weight in a database field table with the type of decimal.

My code:

```php
$p = Product::find($id)->update([
    'weight' => $product['weight'] ? floatval($product['weight']) : null,
]);
```

It always rounds up the number for some reason, even though `dd(floatval($product['weight']))` outputs the correct value, when i try to save it it doesn't save the correct value, only changing the field to the type of float works, but i read that it is not a correct approach.

I'm using MySQL and the Laravel 8.75.

Comment: What is the 'weight' columns datatype ?

Comment: I wrote it above: "I've been trying to save the product weight in a database field table with the type of decimal."

Comment: My bad, here is a helpful post that could provide some clarity on your issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594456/how-do-i-stop-a-mysql-decimal-field-from-being-rounded

Comment: Could you provide the (relevant sections of the) related migration as well? Maybe something's wrong there

Comment: It could be a laravel voyager issue: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3793 i just changed the type to float, i don't think there would be any issues, i will be waiting if anyone has a solution to this though.

Comment: What does your database migration look like? There will be plenty of issues with using `FLOAT`. Floating point integers are not stored with accuracy and often don't behave as people expect. Don't do it unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I don't think there would be any issues with simple ecommerce calculations and with only 2 decimals, i just wanted to use data type decimal for the sake of following good practices.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal type in MySQL has two tuning knobs: precision and scale. You omitted the scale, so it defaults to 0.

### Documentation ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html))

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

### Example

```
mysql> create table test01 (field01 decimal(9));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into test01 (field01) values (123.456);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test01;
+---------+
| field01 |
+---------+
|     123 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table test02 (field01 decimal(9, 4));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test02 (field01) values (123.456);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from test02;
+----------+
| field01  |
+----------+
| 123.4560 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: How does this answer my question using eloquent?

Comment: How do you know what they omitted?

Answer (score 0):

Probably modifying the column with a migration

```
 Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->decimal('weight', 9, 4)->change();
    });
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-decimal)

Comment: Given that you don't know what the current migration looks like, why do you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: Not sure TBH, just I think you could try to do a new migration file changing the scale as you need and test it with a RefreshDatabase trait in a unit test. I hope I helped you.